# using module inside a module for type declaration doesn't compile (TS2503 cannot find namespace)

Tags: typescript

I'm getting a compilation error when I try to do this in typescript (TS2503 cannot find namespace):

```
import mylib = require("./mylib");
let person: mylib.Person = new mylib.Person("A");
```

where I have a `mylib` directory with two files:

```
$ cat mylib/index.ts

import Person = require("./Person");
export = { Person: Person }
```

```
$ cat mylib/Person.ts

export = class Person{
    name: String;

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The problem is with the type declaration `let person: mylib.Person = new mylib.Person("A");`. If I replace it with `let person = new mylib.Person("A");`, it does compile, but I want to declare the type explicitly. At the same time, I want to avoid importing `mylib/Person`. So I want to avoid this solution:

```
import Person = require("./mylib/Person");
let person: Person
```

I decided to put everything in `mylib` to have a single point of access and eliminate the need to import each individual submodule. What's an alternative way to solve the compilation error? Ideallly, I'd access `Person` through a previously imported `mylib` module.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very interesting approach, but the problem is that you can't use types like that (as properties of an object).

Instead, you could do this:

```
import { Person } = require("./mylib");
let person: Person = new Person("A");
```

That way you are using object destructuring and, as you can see, is the usual way of importing classes in TypeScript.

Comment: I was afraid this would still require an explicit import of `Person`. I was trying to replicate what I usually do in plain javascript, where I access everything through a single module, but I guess with types there is some inevitable complexity. Object destructuring still looks like an explicit import of `Person` to me, but I guess it's not too bad, and if that's idiomatic in typescript, that's probably what I should do.